# Change the order from additional checkout fields in WooCommerce checkout manager

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-taxonomy

In Woocommerce, I would like to change additional checkout fields order (programmatically) made with [WooCommerce checkout manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/). This is what I have actually:

[image]

I will need to change the order from 'Rolls per Carton' field after 'Format' field.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce checkout manager plugin **doesn't allow to reorder additional fields** and it save that data in some of his option settings.

So the way is to alter the plugin settings just once.

> To run the following code, just browse any page of your web site. 
>   You will run it just once and then remove it.

The code:

```
function wccs_change_fields_order(){
    $wccs_settings = get_option( 'wccs_settings' );

    // Get the array of additional fields
    $additional_fields = $wccs_settings['buttons'];

    // SETTINGS: Here set your 2 product attribute Names
    $format    = 'Format';
    $rp_carton = 'Rolls per Carton';

    // FIRST Loop Get the array key for 'Rolls per Carton' field label
    foreach( $additional_fields as $key => $field ){
        if( $field['label'] == $rp_carton )
            $key_rp_carton = $key;
    }

    // Save 'Rolls per Carton' data field in a variable
    $field_rp_carton = $additional_fields[$key_rp_carton];

    // Remove 'Rolls per Carton' data field from the fields array
    unset($additional_fields[$key_rp_carton]);

    // Initializing variables
    $new_additional_fields = array();
    $sorting_index = 1;

    // SECOND Loop reordering fields
    foreach( $additional_fields as $key => $field ){
        // Update "order" argument
        $field['order'] = $sorting_index;

        // Add the current field to a new array
        $new_additional_fields[] = $field;

        $sorting_index++; // Increment sorting index

        // When we reach 'Format' data field
        if( $field['label'] == $format ){
            // Set a new position to 'Rolls per Carton' attribute
            $field_rp_carton['order'] = $sorting_index;

            // Add 'Rolls per Carton' field data in the new array
            $new_additional_fields[] = $field_rp_carton;

            $sorting_index++; // Increment sorting index
        }
    }
    // Set back the reordered additional fields in the main array
    $wccs_settings['buttons'] = $new_additional_fields;

    // Update the new changed options (Save)
    update_option( 'wccs_settings', $wccs_settings, 'yes' );
}

wccs_change_fields_order();
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank for your answer